# Give shape to TD in HTML or Text over Img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-shapes

I want to implement,

[image]

And I have implemented so far,

[image]

And code that i have wrriten is like this,

```
  <html>
  <body>
     <hr color="#FFCC66"/>
     <table width="100%" style="color: blue; margin-top: -3;margin-bottom: -3;">
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td align="center" style="font-weight:bolder;" 
                 background="" valign="top">
             <img src="cellbackground.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" />
                Who You Are
             </td>
             <td align="center" style="font-weight:bolder; z-index:1; ">
                 <div style="height:100%; width:100%; 
                      background-origin : content; 
                      background-size:100%;  
                      background-image:url(cellbackground.png) ">
                  Applicant's Needs
                </div>
             </td>

             <td align="center" style="font-weight:bolder;">
                Background Information
             </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     <hr color="#FFCC66"/>
  </body>
  </html>
```

If there is batter way to implement this then please suggest that and if we can give shape to cell border of table then that is very good approach.

Well main point is implementation should support almost all the browsers.

And cellbackground.png file,

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way to shape the border of a cell.  You're on the right track with background images.  Just make the background image of the cell your image, and give the cell a fixed width / height (exactly matching the size of the image).

Comment: Alternatively, you could have gone with your first try and just made the image's position absolute as shown by a quick fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/skwkwfy3/3/

Comment: @JamesGaunt i tried but failed to make it work with IE. all aproach works with all other browsers except IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot shape the table cell. You probably want to use your image as a background and set the size property to `cover` or `contain`:

```css
td.bubble {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ommAw.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center top;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" style="color: blue; margin-top: -3;margin-bottom: -3;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="font-weight:bolder;" background="" class="bubble" valign="top">
               Who You Are</td>
            <td align="center" style="font-weight:bolder; z-index:1; ">
                <div style="height:100%; width:100%; 
                      background-origin : content; 
                      background-size:100%;  
                      background-image:url(cellbackground.png) ">Applicant's Needs</div>
            </td>
            <td align="center" style="font-weight:bolder;">Background Information</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Adjust sizing to suit.

Comment: i tried this sol but instead of bubble it shows <td> filled with orange color. Do i have to reduce size of this img ?

Comment: Did you use the CSS exactly as I have it? Using the `background` shorthand property breaks this technique.

Comment: i figured that it does not work with IE. Can we have sol. which will work with every browser ?

Comment: Sure does work with IE--at least the most recent 3 versions. http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)  and class active

```css
table{
  border-top: 2px solid #ff6600;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6600;
  width: 100%;
  color: blue;
  margin-top: -3px 0;
  padding: 10px 0
}

table td{font-weight:bolder;
  text-align: center; 
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
table td.active{
  background: #ff6600;
  color: white
}
table td.active:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ff6600;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
     <table>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td class=active>
               Who You Are
             </td>
             <td>
                 Applicant's Needs
             </td>

             <td>
                Background Information
             </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Nice. Better than an image.

Comment: Yea!! you removed all the nasty inline styles and deprecated attributes!

Comment: @Tambo i tried this it works very well with browser except IE. By the way this is very cool sol. Can you provide some sol which works with all browsers.

Comment: This should work in IE, also. You really should mention what version(s) you're talking about. They vary wildly in features and standards compliance.

Comment: @isherwood i am taking about IE - 7

Comment: Really? 4 versions behind current? Even Windows XP tolerated IE8, and XP is no longer supported. That's just... ick.